# Is `jQuery.when().done` a deep check for if asynchronous events are done?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Is `jQuery.when().done` a deep check for if asynchronous events are done?

That is, if I have the following code:

```
$.when(ajaxFunc())
.done(myFunc);
```

If `ajaxFunc()` has another asynchronous call, say `ajaxFunc2()` will `myFunc` be executed after `ajaxFunc()` or after `ajaxFunc2()`?

Comment: `when` only considers the *immediate* Promises supplied as arguments. The real trick to using Promises/A is to realize that 1) [*only `then` is required*](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) and 2) *`then` returns a new Promise*: this is where the power of Promises/A shines for "chaining work". Everything else is dressing over this. (jQuery < 1.8 had an incorrect Promises/A implementation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if `ajaxFunc` calls another async function, `$.when` not wait for that second call to complete.

Typically you would use `.then` within `ajaxFunc` to chain to the second call:

```
function ajaxFunc() {
    return $.ajax(...).then(ajaxFunc2);
}
```

The `.then` chain will only call `ajaxFunc2` when the `$.ajax` is complete, but then returns a new promise that is the result of `ajaxFunc2`.  It's then *that* promise that's passed to `$.when()`.